# Should I delete QPointer in the destructor of the class?

Tags: c++, qt, c++14, qpointer

Suppose I have a class like the following:

```
#include <Object>
#include <QProcess>

class MyClass: public QObject {
private:
    QPointer<QProcess> m_process{ nullptr };
public:
    MyClass(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QObject{ parent }
        , m_process{new QProcess{} }
    {
        QObject::connect(m_process, &QProcess::errorOccurred,
            this, [](QProcess::ProcessError error) {
            qDebug() << "error: " << error;
            });
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        if (m_process)  delete m_process; //--> is it necessary?
    }
};
```

**Should I need to have the delete the `m_process` manually** as shown in the destructor?

Unfortunately, I can not use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, as of

```
QObject::connect(m_process, &QProcess::errorOccurred,
            this, [](QProcess::ProcessError error) {
            qDebug() << "error: " << error;
            });
```

I have not seen a proper overload for `QObject::connect`.

On the other hand in [QPointer::~QPointer()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html#dtor.QPointer) I have read:

> Destroys the guarded pointer. Just like a normal pointer, destroying a
>   guarded pointer does not destroy the object being pointed to.

That means `QPointer::~QPointer()` will delete as `MyClass`'s object go out of scope, and hence I am deleting the `m_process` twice?

Or did I misunderstood?

Comment: You don't have to. You can use QSharedPointer or QScopedPointer as an alternative.

Comment: "I have not seen a proper overload for QObject::connect." - You can just pass `ptr.get()` if you have a `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Actually this post [Why don't the official Qt examples and tutorials use smart pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433435/why-dont-the-official-qt-examples-and-tutorials-use-smart-pointers) stopped me to do that and rethink about using smart pointers.

Comment: @mohabouje I am not quite sure about, QT's smart pointers. Rather I trust **`std::`smart pointers**.

Comment: @Const It's certainly a good idea to think twice about it. As mentioned in the answers, in your particular sample you don't need *any* kind of pointer. But if you do, the `get()` member is how you get a raw pointer out. Just don't let that raw pointer dangle by letting the smart pointer go out of scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purpose of `QPointer` is to provide a guarded or weak pointer to a `QObject` subclass. It does not delete the object when it goes out of scope, it just knows if the object it points to is alive or deleted already.

So your current code is correct in that sense. A few comments:

- It's not useful to have default value `nullptr` for the pointer in variable declaration, because you initialized it in the constructor initializer list.
- You don't need to check if a pointer is null before deleting, because `delete nullptr;` is valid code which just does nothing.
- If the lifetime of your `QProcess` is same as the lifetime of the containing object, then you should just put it as a member variable, and not use `new` at all, unless you have some specific reason.
- If you do want to use `new` to allocate it, consider if the `QProcess` could have a parent `QObject`, which will delete it.
- Alternatively, you should wrap the pointer in `QScopedPointer` or `std::unique_ptr`, because they own the object they point to and will delete it when they go out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for the review. Upped +1.  I would prefer not to have pointers since it doesn't require here, in the current situation.

Answer (score 1):

`QPointer` is not a smart pointer. It does not manage the object it points to. It just tracks whether or not it was deleted. You will need to delete it yourself:

```
~MyClass()
{
    delete m_process.data();
}
```

When you delete the pointed-to object, `data()` will be null.

You don't need to check if it's null before deleting it, because deleting a null pointer is OK (it just doesn't do anything.)

I don't think you need a `QPointer` here though. As said before, this class is only useful for tracking whether or not the object has been deleted elsewhere. You should probably not be using a pointer at all here. Just do:

```
#include <QProcess>

class MyClass: public QObject {
private:
    QProcess m_process;
// ...
```

And change your connect code to:

```
connect(&m_process, &QProcess::errorOccurred, this, [](QProcess::ProcessError error)
{
    qDebug() << "error: " << error;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Upped +1.  I would prefer not to have pointers since it doesn't require here, in the current situation.